# Trying to deploy my first google cloud function - express not found

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to deploy my first google cloud function, the code of which is here:

https://github.com/rldaulton/GCF-Stripe/blob/master/Charge%20Customer/index.js

It starts with this line:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
```

However I get this error when I try and deploy with Node6 and execute function name chargeCustomer:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:1:91)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

It seems like I’m missing module express. How do I add this?

Comment: `npm install express`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deploy a Node.js code function with Cloud Functions the responsibility is on you to also supply a well formed package.json file which declares the dependencies your function needs which usually match the `requires()` statements within your code.  In your example, your code requires express so you would have to supply a package.json that declares that you require express.  For example:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

Here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) to the documentation at Google relating to dependencies for Node.js for Cloud Functions.